# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cog'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Hello I wrote this bot which uses cogs and I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MainBot.py", line 42, in <module>
    bot.load_extension('Cog.Ship')
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 660, in load_extension
    spec = importlib.util.find_spec(name)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\importlib\util.py", line 94, in find_spec
    parent = __import__(parent_name, fromlist=['__path__'])
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cog'
```

Here is my main file:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='al_', case_insensitive=True)

@bot.event
async def on_connect():
    print('Bot Online!')

bot.load_extension('Cog.Ship')
bot.run("No Token for you")
```

and here is my cog file:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import random

class Ship(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    
    @commands.command()
    async def ship(self, message):        
        line = message.content
        name = line.split(' ')[1]
        name2 = line.split(' ')[2]
        labels = {0: "Awful", 1: "Bad", 2 : "Pretty Low", 3 : "Not Great", 4 : "Not Too Bad", 5 : "Barely", 6 : "Not Bad", 7 : "Pretty Good", 8 : "Great", 9: "Amazing", 10 : "**PERFECT**"}
        number = random.randint(0,100)
        label = labels[int(number/10)]
        await message.channel.send(f":heartpulse:**MATCHMAKING**:heartpulse:\n:small_red_triangle_down:`{name}`\n:small_red_triangle:`{name2}`\n**{number}%** **{label}** :heart:")
            

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Ship(bot))
```

I was able to write this in one file but as you might know, cogs would make my code so much more organized

---

if the folder that “Ship.py” is in is called “Cog”, then this will be correct

Comment: try `pip install cogapp`

Comment: What is your directory structure. The current code to load in the cog. Assumes that there is a cog directory

Comment: @itsvinayak cogapp has nothing to do with the Discord API.

Comment: I've tried replicating your setup locally, it's functional on my end. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62371376/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-cogs) might help you.

Comment: Do you have a folder called "Cog"? or your cog file isint in your folder called "Cog"

Comment: everything has been fixed, all that had to be done was rename the folder from "Cog" to "cog"